# BPM 6.4 not saving properties bug?

Tags: redhat-bpm

I’m using BPM 6.4 with all the defaults when installing. I created a business process which has a signal event in "Catching Intermediate Events", and I am trying to change the property ‘Cancel Activity’ from true -> false. The default is true. I change it to false, then I save my business process, reload the page and the property ‘Cancel Activity’ has changed back to true. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

The cancel activity property only is used in specific use cases, for example when it is used as a boundary event (to indicate if the node it is attached to should be canceled or not when the event happens).  In situations where the property is not used, the value will not be persisted.   We are looking at improving this in our new version by making sure the property is hidden / not editable in cases where it is not useful.